# DirectX 11 GetDisplayModeList() fails in Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: c++, windows, directx, directx-11, direct3d

Good afternoon,

I have a barebone Direct3D App that works on a host PC, but fails to initialize DirectX while running via remote desktop.

I traced the failure to this call, where it fails with

```
    result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, NULL);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }
```

It fails with:

`result = 0x887a0022 : A resource is not available at the time of the call, but may become available later.`

The full initialization code is from Rastertek tutorials, found here:
http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut03.html

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Comment: It's known to fail with remote desktop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgioutput-getdisplaymodelist

Comment: There's a lot of code in the tutorial about display modes that aren't particularly useful for a 'windowed' mode. You can just maximize a window with a borderless window to get the same effect. See [Direct3D Game VS Templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) and the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). There's lots of useful stuff in Rastertek, but they use [deprecated D3DX](https://aka.ms/dxsdk) and a lot of excessive infrastructure so you really shouldn't assume they are using the 'best choice'.

Answer (score 2):

Remote Desktop involves some corner-cases, and keep in mind it's sometimes using the 'Microsoft Basic Renderer' (a.k.a. the software WARP driver). See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

You can also guard your use of `GetDisplayModeList` in the remote scenario by detecting it in the first place. For example, the [legacy DXUT sample framework](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT/wiki) did this in it's enumeration code:

```cpp
// mode for the current screen resolution for the remote session.
if( 0 != GetSystemMetrics( SM_REMOTESESSION) )
{
    DEVMODE DevMode;
    DevMode.dmSize = sizeof( DEVMODE );
    if( EnumDisplaySettings( nullptr, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &DevMode ) )
    {
        NumModes = 1;
        pDesc[0].Width = DevMode.dmPelsWidth;
        pDesc[0].Height = DevMode.dmPelsHeight;
        pDesc[0].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        pDesc[0].RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
        pDesc[0].RefreshRate.Denominator = 0;
        pDesc[0].ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_PROGRESSIVE;
        pDesc[0].Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_CENTERED;
    }
}
```

You also can't use 'full-screen exclusive' mode in remote desktop:

```
if( GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION) != 0 )
{
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;
}
```

> You don't really need to use `GetDisplayModeList` at all. Just pick a reasonable starting size or start your window 'maximized'. See the [directx-vs-templates](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux/) for an approach that just uses the 'native resolution' of the desktop for both windowed and 'fake full screen'. It also all works well for remote desktop.

Another 'corner-case' with remote desktop is "raw input" for mouse. See the implementation of [Mouse](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/Mouse.cpp) from the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 0):

Not technically a solution, but the problem was in refresh rate initialization, bypassing this with a try{}-catch{} block allowed me to run with a default refresh rate via remote desktop. Everything else initialized without issues